# inserting text from a label as part of an email body

Tags: ios, email, datepicker

I am building an app where you use a datepicker to select your desired date. Once a button is clicked the date appears as a label and a text field. I have a separate button that creates an email. How can I incorporate the date selected into the body of the email? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Xcode is an inappropriate tag for your question.  The bigger question here is:  is your app meant for MacOS or iOS or?

Comment: apologies its for iOS. I will remove the xcode tag and replace it with ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your email code, when you open your mfmailcomposer sheet.

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:yoursubject];


    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourlabel.text];

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

Comment: Thank you so much this has been bugging for nearly a week now. I have used the code and it works. This makes the body = to the text in the label. I was hoping to have a preset text set out for the body [picker setMessageBody:@"Thank you fro your request, you have selected that you are available on"                                and the last line is filled in from the date from a label.

Comment: actually not to worry just had a thought. if the body is going to be emailBody i should look at editing that as if by magic the pieces have fallen in place and it works. Thanks for your help Im new to xcode and find this all exciting when things work or im able to piece things together lol. Once again thanks for your help.